# Yaesu FT-817 Won't transmit Dig, SSB or CW

Tags: transceiver, mobile, yaesu, equipment-troubleshooting, repair

I have a problem with my Yaesu FT-817 it Won't transmit Dig, SSB or CW, But it does transmit AM, FM and Pkt on all bands. Does anyone know what the problem might be. The Radio receives fine on all bands.

When I press the ptt the transmit light comes on but there is no power being sent to the Antenna. On AM FM I get power readings on my Meter on all bands HF and VHF but On SSB and CW there is no power leaving the radio.

I assume if the finals where blown I would not be getting any output what so ever. I am hoping someone else that owns this radio as seen this issue in the past.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular radio, but I suspect you'll need to provide a lot more information in order to get a useful response. What exactly does it mean that it "won't transmit?" Does it say it's transmitting, but actually doesn't? Does it issue some kind of error? Or is it the case that simply nothing happens when you press the PTT? What troubleshooting steps have you taken so far?

Comment: ...Yaesu tech support is usually easy to reach in the U.S.  (714) 827-7600

Comment: You can use the PTT to generate a Morse tone Kind Regards Glyn

Answer (score 3):

SSB requires a signal from the microphone: only when you are talking there is a signal generated. For CW you need to connect a morse key or paddle to have output signal. When FM and AM are operational there is nothing wrong with your power amplifier. In case of a defect: check the microphone by listening to the AM or FM output signal and when that is ok and ssb still doesn't work, check the menu settings for SSB gain, audio, filter, etc. PA0FSB

Answer (score 2):

Menu option for ssb filter (38?) should be "off", if no filter.

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to the site, and nice first answer!